# Is it possible to access the clientId from an authToken (RequestContext) in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have implemented Oauth with my WebAPI 2 application and there are several applications access the API. Once authenticated, after making a request whilst sending across the auth token, I can access the user as follows:

```
var currentUser = RequestContext.Principal;
```

When logging in, the `clientId` was set as follows:

```
context.OwinContext.Set<AppClient>("oauth:client", client);
```

Is there a way to access that client Id? I want to restrict certain actions / controllers to certain clients. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried getting the client as follows:

```
var client = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<string>("oauth:client");
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When logging in you can set a claim on the identity in the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("oauth:client", client));
```

That way it is available once the User Principal's Identity has be set.

You can create an extension method to extract it conveniently

```
public static class GenericIdentityExtensions {
    const string ClientIdentifier = "oauth:client";

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the client id claim
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool SetClientId(this IIdentity identity, string clientId) {
        if (identity != null) {
            var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity != null) {
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClientIdentifier, clientId));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the client id claim
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetClientId(this IIdentity identity) {
        if (identity != null) {
            var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity != null) {
                return claimsIdentity.FindFirstOrEmpty(ClientIdentifier);
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the first claim that is matched by the specified type if it exists, String.Empty otherwise.
    /// </summary>
    public static string FindFirstOrEmpty(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType) {
        var claim = identity.FindFirst(claimType);
        return claim == null ? string.Empty : claim.Value;
    }
}
```

So now once you have the the user principal you can extract the client id from the claims.

```
var currentUser = RequestContext.Principal;
var client = currentUser.Identity.GetClientId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AuthenticationProperties` instead. Same as answered, in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` just implement next stuff while ticket issuing:

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "client_id", clientId
    },
});

var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
context.Validated(ticket);
```

Then, you'll be able to get value via `context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["client_id"];`